# How do you save additional parameters using Reform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reform

Here is my main Reform Form object;

```
class CardHolderSupplierForm < ApplicationForm
  property :supplier_id, validates: { presence: true }
  property :standing_order, form: StandingOrderForm
end
```

And the StandingOrderForm is;

```
class StandingOrderForm < ApplicationForm
  property :amount_pence
  property :reference
  property :frequency
end
```

I have a column in standing_orders called `amount_currency` that should always be "GBP". I cannot seem to get Reform to just shove this in for me. I have tried various ways;

```
class StandingOrderForm < ApplicationForm
  property :amount_pence
  property :reference
  property :frequency

  # does nothing
  def amount_currency
    "GBP"
  end

  # does nothing - can't even binding.pry
  def save
    model.amount_currency = "GBP"
    super
  end
```

I don't know how to get this working. The rest of the form works as normal.

Comment: If you want to do this without the reform gem I can show you how since Rails makes it easy.  Then you won't have to worry about playing nice with a prebuilt library and can customize things as normal.  Let me know if you're stuck and I'll show you how to setup form objects the Rails way.

Comment: thanks for the offer but it's a work project not a personal one and I am tied to Reform for this.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Reform's default value setting?

```
property :amount_currency, default: "GBP"
```